# Spark and 100000k of sequential HTTP calls: driver vs workers

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have to do 100000 sequential HTTP requests with Spark. I have to store responses into S3. I said sequential, because each request returns around 50KB of data, and I have to keep 1 second in order to not exceed API rate limits.

*Where to make HTTP calls: from Spark Job's code (executed on driver/master node) or from dataset transformation (executed on worker node)?*

### Workarrounds

1. Make HTTP request from my Spark job (on Driver/Master node), create dataset of each HTTP response (each contains 5000 json items) and save each dataset to S3 with help of spark. You do not need to keep dataset after you saved it
2. Create dataset from all 100000 URLs (move all further computations to workers), make HTTP requests inside `map` or `mapPartition`, save single dataset to S3.

### The first option

It's simpler and it represents a nature of my compurations - they're sequential, because of 1 second delay. But:

1. *Is it bad to make 100_000 HTTP calls from Driver/Master node?*
2. *Is it more efficient to create/save one 100_000 * 5_000 dataset than creating/saving 100_000 small datasets of size 5_000*
3. *Each time I creating dataset from HTTP response - I'll move response to worker and then save it to S3, right?* Double shuffling than...

### Second option

Actually it won't benefit from parallel processing, since you have to keep interval of 1 second because request. The only bonus is to moving computations (even if they aren't too hard) from driver. But:

1. *Is it worth of moving computations to workers?*
2. *Is it a good idea to make API call inside transformation?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saving a file <32MB (or whatever fs.s3a.block.size is) to S3 is ~2xGET, 1xLIST and a PUT; you get billed a bit by AWS for each of these calls, plus storage costs.

For larger files, a POST to initiate multipart upload after that first block, one POST per 32 MB (of 32MB, obviously) and a final POST of a JSON file to complete. So: slightly more efficient

Where small S3 sizes matter is in the bills from AWS and followup spark queries: anything you use in spark, pyspark, SQL etc. many small files are slower: Theres a high cost in listing files in S3, and every task pushed out to a spark worker has some setup/commit/complete costs.

regarding doing HTTP API calls inside a worker, well, you can do fun things there. If the result isn't replicable then task failures & retries can give bad answers, but for a GET it should be OK. What is hard is throttling the work; I'll leave you to come up with a strategy there.

Here's an example of [uploading files to S3 or other object store in workers](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/cloud-integration/blob/master/spark-cloud-integration/src/main/scala/com/hortonworks/spark/cloud/applications/CloudCp.scala); first the RDD of the copy src/dest operations is built up, then they are pushed out to workers. The result of the worker code includes upload duration length info, if someone ever wanted to try and aggregate the stats (though there you'd probably need timestamp for some time series view)

Given you have to serialize the work to one request/second,  100K requests is going to take over a day. if each request takes <1 second, you may as well run it on a single machine. What's important is to save the work incrementally so that if your job fails partway through you can restart from the last checkpoint. I'd personally focus on that problem: how could do this operation such that every 15-20 minutes of work was saved, and on a restart you can carry on from there.

Spark does not handle recovery of a failed job, only task failures. Lose the driver and you get to restart your last query. Break things up.

Something which comes to mind could be
* first RDD takes list of queries and some summary info about any existing checkpointed data, calculates the next 15 minutes of work, 
* building up a list of GET calls to delegate to 1+ worker. Either 1 URL/row, or have multiple URLs in a single row
* run that job, save the results
* test recovery works with a smaller window and killing things.
* once happy: do the full run

Maybe also: recognise & react to any throttle events coming off the far end by 
1. Sleeping in the worker
1. returning a count of throttle events in the results, so that the driver can initially collect aggregate stats and maybe later tune sleep window for subsequent tasks.

Comment: no worries -tell us how you get on once you've done it!